# Firestore structure data - offers and users node

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am going to make an Android app that have two tabs. First tab display all the offers and a user can like any offer. The second tab display the user favorite offers. I want when the user first time open the app he can see all the offers without login.

The offers collection have the following fields:

```
offers {  --collection
     offerid{ --document
              {
                name
                desc
                img
               }
           }
      }
```

The users collection have the following fields:

```
users { --collection
     userid{  --document
              {
                firstname
                lastname
                desc
                img
                phoneNumber 
               }
           }
}
```

My question is how to have a relationship between the offers and the users node?

I tried to have a subcollection for the users collection called likedoffers there i store same information of an offer in a document.

```
users { --collection
     userid{
              {
                firstname
                lastname
                desc
                img
                phoneNumber 
                 {likedoffers --collection
                   {
                    firstname
                    lastname
                    desc
                    img
                    phoneNumber 
                   }
                 }
               }

           }
}
```

But i want to avoid duplicates of information. can you help me what that please?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48240887/5861618)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes but i will have more than 1 million users and one document in firestore is limited to 20.000 properties and 1mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, I recomand you have a Cloud Firestore database structure which should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- userId1 (document)
   |           |
   |           --- //user details
   |
   --- offers (collection)
         |
         --- userId1 (document)
               |
               --- userOffers (collection)
                      |
                      --- offerId1 (document)
                             |
                             --- isFavorite: true
                             |
                             --- //offer details
```

To get all offers that belong to a single user, just query your database to get all offers (documents) within `userOffers` collection. To get only the favorite offers, query your database to get all offers (documents) within `userOffers` collection using `.whereEqualTo("isFavorite", true)`. For the first situation you only need to use a `CollectionReference` like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference offersRef = rootRef
    .collection("offers")
    .document(userId1)
    .collection("userOffers");
```

And then loop through the `userOffers` collection to get all the offers documents, not matter if is a favorite or not.

For the second situation, you need to use a `query` like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference offersRef = rootRef
    .collection("offers")
    .document(userId1)
    .collection("userOffers");
Query query = offersRef.whereEqualTo("isFavorite", true);
```

You need to do the same thing but this you'll only get the favorite offers.

I have not included in this database structure the details like, firstname, lastname and other such details, so you can focus on the relations between collections and documents.

Acording to your last comment, your database structure should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- userId1 (document)
   |           |
   |           --- //user details
   |
   --- offers (collection)
         |
         --- offerId1 (document)
                |
                --- isFavorite: true
                |
                --- users
                |     |
                |     --- userId1: true
                |     |
                |     --- userId2: true
                |
                --- //offer details
```

To query for all offers for non-authenticated users:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference offersRef = rootRef.collection("offers");
```

For the second situation, this is the query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference offersRef = rootRef.collection("offers");
Query query = offersRef.whereEqualTo("users." + userId1, true).whereEqualTo("isFavorite", true);
```

In this case, don't forget to add the index that that will appear in the logcat.

Comment: As i mentioned the app have two tabs the first tab display all the offers (doest matter if the user added them to the favorite list or not). If i use your solution then how to get all the offers. I want when the user first time open the app to see all the offers without login.

Comment: lets say X user downloaded the app and opened it. if i use ur solution no offer will be displayed because the user hasnt logged in yet and dont have a userid. Your solution depending on the userid.

Comment: If you don't want to use authentication, then you can generate a unique id yourself for each user. But authentication, is the practice when it comes to something like this. It allows you to have favorite offers for each user separately, which i understand is what you are looking for. Am I wrong?

Comment: You have right, but i want to have two options for the users of the app. first to see all the offers without need to login and second option to log in and be able to add an offer to the favorite list.

Comment: I have added another database structure. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Alex i really appreciate your time, but in Firestore a single document can have only 20,000 properties and  1MB size limit. So i cant use ur recent solution.

Comment: In none of my examples we can talk about this constraint. In the last example an `offerId` document has **`5 properties`** (name, desc, img, isFavorite and `users` which is an object), not 20,000. I don't understand why you are worried, can you tell me?

Comment: Because i cant have more than 20.000 users ^^ think if i get more than 1 million users :(

Comment: You have misunderstood the concept. Cloud Firestore restriction is for the number of properties, which in your case is 5! There is no limitation regarding the number of documents. You can have as many users as you want. There will be no problem. Is it ok now?

Comment: Please see also the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) in which is said that 20,000 is for `Maximum sum of the following for a document: The number of single-field index entries and
The number of composite index entries`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. i thought the limit apply on the object also. Your my hero, big respect <3

Answer (score 0):

Change your Json Format to

```
"offers" : {
    "81d19e85-8c6c-4824-9fb1-61a7cd316e32" : {
      "offerName" : "offer",
      "offerId" : "81d19e85-8c6c-4824-9fb1-61a7cd316e32",

    },
"e2ec0556-4420-4d2f-b346-0b5cebeb1ebe" : {
   "offerName" : "offer",
  "offerId" : "e2ec0556-4420-4d2f-b346-0b5cebeb1ebe",

}
```

and then on save get offer Id and store in favorite offers node.!

Create node favorite offers and then add query like

```
String id = offer.getOfferId(); //offer id
```

`mdatabaseref.child("favorite offers ").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(id).setValue(offer)` and get favorite  offers of each user by using their user Id.!

and to avoid duplicate save

hope this help you.!